# HDFS block size Vs actual file size

Tags: hdfs, filesize

I know that HDFS stores data using the regular linux file system in the data nodes. My HDFS block size is `128 MB`. Lets say that I have `10 GB` of disk space in my hadoop cluster that means, HDFS initially has `80 blocks` as available storage.

If I create a small file of say `12.8 MB`, #available HDFS blocks will become 79. What happens if I create another small file of `12.8 MB`? Will the #availbale blocks stay at 79 or will it come down to 78? In the former case, HDFS basically recalculates the #available blocks after each block allocation based on the available free disk space so, #available blocks will become 78 only after more than 128 MB of disk space is consumed. Please clarify.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The best way to know is to try it, see my results bellow.

But before trying, my guess is that even if you can only allocate 80 **full** blocks in your configuration, you can allocate more than 80 non-empty files.  This is because I think HDFS does not use a full block each time you allocate a non-empty file.  Said in another way, HDFS blocks are not a *storage allocation* unit, but a *replication* unit.  I think the storage allocation unit of HDFS is the unit of the underlying filesystem (if you use ext4 with a block size of 4 KB and you create a 1 KB file in a cluster with replication factor of 3, you consume 3 times 4 KB = 12 KB of hard disk space).

Enough guessing and thinking, let's try it.  My lab configuration is as follow:

- hadoop version 1.0.4
- 4 data nodes, each with a little less than 5.0G of available space, ext4 block size of 4K
- block size of 64 MB, default replication of 1

After starting HDFS, I have the following NameNode summary:

- 1 files and directories, 0 blocks = 1 total
- DFS Used: 112 KB
- DFS Remaining: 19.82 GB

Then I do the following commands:

- `hadoop fs -mkdir /test`
- `for f in $(seq 1 10); do hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ./1K_file /test/$f; done`

With these results:

- 12 files and directories, 10 blocks = 22 total
- DFS Used: 122.15 KB
- DFS Remaining: 19.82 GB

So the 10 files did not consume 10 times 64 MB (no modification of "DFS Remaining").

Comment: This is what I was guessing. Now it is clearer. Thanks for the detailed explanation and the experiment!

Answer (score 1):

HDFS use only what it needs on the local file system. So block, representing 12 MB file will take 12 MB when stored (on each datanode where it is stored).
So you will be able to have as much blocks as you need assuming you have space for the data.

Comment: But I think HDFS decides whether it has enough free space in terms of the #available blocks. Hypothetically, if we have disk space of 128 MB and create an 1MB file, then #available blocks becomes 0 (since 127 MB can not make up a complete HDFS block) and HDFS will not be able to create another 1MB file even though there is enough disk space. Does that sound correct?

Comment: From my experiance - HDFS will try to create block and will return error on out of space on concrete nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The 'available blocks' will stay at 79 ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678235/how-hdfs-calculate-the-available-blocks)). Anyway I don't think HDFS decides whether it has enough free space in terms of the 'available blocks'.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS block size and Ext block size are not the same thing. The easiest way to put it is HDFS block size is "replication" block size, not "storage" block size.

For storage it will use the same amount of space as your local file system does,because that's what it uses, but it will copy not less, than one block between nodes, even if only 1KB is used