# Are multiple files stored in a single block?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I store many small files into HDFS, will they get stored in a single block?

In my opinion, these small files should get stored into a single block according to this discussion:
[HDFS block size Vs actual file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062457/hdfs-block-size-vs-actual-file-size)

Answer (score 13):

Quoting from **Hadoop - The Definitive Guide**:

> HDFS stores small files inefficiently, since **each file is stored in a block**, and block
>   metadata is held in memory by the namenode. Thus, a large number of small files can
>   eat up a lot of memory on the namenode. (Note, however, that small files do not take
>   up any more disk space than is required to store the raw contents of the file. For
>   example, a 1 MB file stored with a block size of 128 MB uses 1 MB of disk space, not
>   128 MB.)
>   **Hadoop Archives**, or HAR files, are a file archiving facility that packs files into HDFS
>   blocks more efficiently, thereby reducing namenode memory usage while still allowing
>   transparent access to files.

**Conclusion:** Each file will get stored in a separate block.

Comment: For example, a 1 MB file stored with a block size of 128 MB uses 1 MB of disk space, not 128 MB.) How does hdfs use the remaining 127M in this block?

Answer (score 2):

Below is what specified in Hadoop Definitive Guide:

> Unlike a filesystem for a single disk, a file in HDFS that is smaller
>   than a single block  does not occupy a full block’s worth of
>   underlying storage

For example, if you have 30 MB file and your block size is of 64 MB, then this file will get stored in one block logically, but in the physical file system, HDFS uses only 30 MB to store the file. The remaining 30 MB will be free to use.

Comment: file will get stored in one block logically? what does logically here mean?

Comment: "one block logically" means when mapreduce is launched maptask will consider this 30mb file as one block for processing(only if the split size is same as hdfs block size)

Answer (score 1):

each block belongs to only one file,just do like below:
1.use fsck command to get block info of file:

```
hadoop fsck /gavial/data/OB/AIR/PM25/201709/01/15_00.json -files -blocks
```

out put like this:

```
    /gavial/data/OB/AIR/PM25/201709/01/15_00.json 521340 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
0. BP-1004679263-192.168.130.151-1485326068364:blk_1074920015_1179253 len=521340 repl=3

Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    521340 B
 Total dirs:    0
 Total files:   1
 Total symlinks:        0
 Total blocks (validated):  1 (avg. block size 521340 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   1 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:    0 (0.0 %)
```

block id is

```
blk_1074920015
```

2.use fsck command to show block status,out put like this

hdfs fsck -blockId blk_1074920015

```
Block Id: blk_1074920015
Block belongs to: /gavial/data/OB/AIR/PM25/201709/01/15_00.json
No. of Expected Replica: 3
No. of live Replica: 3
No. of excess Replica: 0
No. of stale Replica: 0
No. of decommission Replica: 0
No. of corrupted Replica: 0
Block replica on datanode/rack: datanode-5/default-rack is HEALTHY
Block replica on datanode/rack: datanode-1/default-rack is HEALTHY
```

obviously,the block belongs to only one file

Answer (score -2):

Yes. when you store large number of small files, they get stored in a single block until the block has equal space to accommodate. 
But the inefficiency comes because for each of these small files, there will be an indexing entry(filename,block,offset) gets created in the namenode for each small file. This wastes up the memory reserved for metadata in the namenode if we have many small files instead of small number of very large files.

Comment: blocks are logical not physical, a single block cannot hold morethan one file and space left after in every block can be used by other blocks.

Comment: This does not seem to be the correct understanding, as already discussed by other members.