# processing the last block of data in HADOOP

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

Suppose the data size of a file XYZ, is 68MB. So the blocks (where default block is 64MB) will be A- 64MB and B - 4MB. 
In the B block, rest of the space is occupied by another data block.

So when processing is done for XYZ data file, the A anb B blocks data will be processed. Since B block
contains data for another file too, how does the HADOOP know which part of the block is to processed in case
of B block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have file (`XYZ`) of 68 MB and assuming your block size being `64MB` then the data will be split into 2 blocks. Block-A will store `64MB` of data and then the Block-B will store rest of the `4MB` and the block will be closed (there is no wastage of space here), no other file's data will be put into Block-B.

So while processing, MapReduce knows exactly which blocks to process for a specific file. Of course, there are other constraints like input split's which are taken into consideration by MapReduce while processing the blocks to figure out record boundaries.

Comment: You mean to say, in case of Block B it will be again divided into two chunks. One with size of 4MB and remaining for other data. Right!!!

Comment: No, HDFS blocks are just logical abstractions around physical linux file system, so the second block is just stored as 4 MB logical file in HDFS and 1 metadata entry in the NameNode for that block. But under the hoods block is technically stored as 1000 linux blocks = 4MB (assuming `4KB` ext4 block size). Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062457/hdfs-block-size-vs-actual-file-size) for more info.